# How to add user managed replication in GCP Secret Manager using Python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

How to add user managed replication in GCP Secret Manager using Python
Below for the automatic replication

```
response = client.create_secret(parent, secret_id, {
    'replication': {
        'automatic': {},
    },
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved as follows

```
# Create the secret.
response = client.create_secret(parent, secret_id, {
    'replication': {
        'user_managed': {'replicas': [{'location': 'europe-north1'}]},
    },
})
```

Complete Source : https://github.com/deepakkallungal/gcp/blob/master/python/create-secret-user-managed.py

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look to the [API documentation](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.secrets#Replication)

```
 'replication': {
   'user_managed': {
      'replicas': [
         'location': 'us-east1',
         'location': 'us-central1'
       ]
    },
 },
```

Comment: This is actually the REST reference. I am looking for Python implementation.